# TYPO3 ExtBase - Get scheduler task by UID and execute it

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a task in my scheduler with ID 5:

[image: task in schedueler]

Now I try to fetch the Task and then execute it.

```
...

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler
 * @inject
 */
protected $scheduler;

...

public function createAction($filepath, Strategy $strategy)
{
    ...
    $taskObject = $this->scheduler->fetchTaskRecord(5)["serialized_task_object"];

    $task = unserialize($taskObject);

    if ($this->scheduler->isValidTaskObject($task)) {

        // The task is valid, return it
        $this->scheduler->executeTask($task);
    }

    ...
}
```

But I get the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function saveTask() on null in /var/www/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.25/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Task/AbstractTask.php on line 469`

This is what I get if I execute `var_dump($taskObject);`

> string(588)
>   "O:32:"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Scheduler\Task":9:{s:20:"*commandIdentifier";s:39:"importr:import:initializeservicemanager";s:12:"*arguments";a:1:{s:12:"extensionKey";s:0:"";}s:11:"*defaults";a:2:{s:12:"extensionKey";N;s:4:"mail";N;}s:10:"*taskUid";i:5;s:11:"*disabled";b:1;s:12:"*execution";O:29:"TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Execution":6:{s:8:"*start";i:1475152860;s:6:"*end";i:1475152860;s:11:"*interval";i:0;s:11:"*multiple";i:0;s:10:"*cronCmd";s:0:"";s:23:"*isNewSingleExecution";b:0;}s:16:"*executionTime";i:1475152860;s:14:"*description";s:0:"";s:12:"*taskGroup";i:0;}"

If I output `$task` with `var_dump` right after the isValidTaskObject check, then I just get an empty page.

To be more precise, I am working inside the `createAction` function from the file `Importr/Classes/Controller/ImportrController.php` which is part of the extension `Importr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should just use `fetchTask()` instead of `fetchTaskRecord()`, to get the task object instead of an array.
I just tried this and got no error.

```
$scheduler = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler::class);
$schedulerTask = $scheduler->fetchTask(1);
$schedulerTask->execute();
```

Not much but at least a bit information / documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/latest/DevelopersGuide/SchedulerApi/Index.html

HTH
merzilla

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why `fetchTask()` is not documented in the API, it would safe me many hours